# Unable to swap all key value pairs using json

Tags: javascript, linux

Unable to swap json key value pair. I attached a JSFiddle for the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/j1acz4dp/4/

```
console.log(swap({"MYR":"_code","CNY":"_code","JPY":"_code"});
console.log(swap({A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}));

function swap(json){
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in json){
    ret[json[key]] = key;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The outcome I am expecting is:

```
{_code:"MYR",_code:"CNY",_code:"JPY"}
```

But the output I get is:

```
{ _code: "JPY" }
```

This is wrong.

Comment: The expected results aren't valid. An object can't have duplicate keys. That's why you are getting the result you are showing

Comment: Hi charlietfl thanks for reply, but i not understand well but are not both of them are same? 
{"MYR":"_code","CNY":"_code","JPY":"_code"}< able to change the last object key+ value only
{'A' : '1', 'B': '2', 'C' : '3', 'D' : '4'} < able to change all object key + value

Comment: Those are ok. It's `{_code:"MYR",_code:"CNY",_code:"JPY"}` which becomes simply `{ _code: "JPY" }` because it's doing `ret._code="MYR"`, then `ret._code="CNY"` then `ret._code="JPY"`

Comment: Thanks charlietfl  _code are the duplicated key , thanks for make me notice my mistake

Comment: Hi @charlietfl is that anyway to make {"MYR":"_code","CNY":"_code","JPY":"_code"} become  {_code:"MYR",_code:"CNY",_code:"JPY"}  ??

Comment: No...it's not valid. Could do `[{_code:"MYR"}, {_code:"CNY"}, {_code:"JPY"}]`

Comment: How can we achieve that? [{_code:"MYR"}, {_code:"CNY"}, {_code:"JPY"}] . Can you provide sample ? appreciate

Answer (score 0):

> How can we achieve that? `[{_code:"MYR"}, {_code:"CNY"}, {_code:"JPY"}]`

```js
c = {"MYR":"_code","CNY":"_code","JPY":"_code"}
r = Object.entries(c).map( ([k,v]) => ({[v]:k}) )
console.log(r);
```